# Dynamic php pages getting direct traffic

Tags: dynamic, high-traffic, bounce-rate

I just launched a website and for the 1st 30 days was only getting word of mouth traffic with good analytic #s. Bounce rate around 32% and average of 3 minutes visit duration. Now that I've submitted a sitemap, I am getting about 72% bounce rate and only 1 min on the site. The weirdest thing is the direct traffic landing on dynamic php pages is the bulk of the high bounce rate and most of them show 0 seconds for duration. I submitted these dynamic pages in my site map so wondering if someone is using that information and crawling my site???? Example of the dynamic urls:

```
www.example.com/good-gas-station-new-york-ny.html
www.example.com/bp-gas-station-miami-fl.html
```

Any ideas of what it could be? Should I be worried?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably seeing bots of some sort. They're very common online, used by everyone from large search engines (good) to e-mail spammers (bad). Just make sure they don't recognize things like e-mail addresses that don't help your SEO anyway, and it should be fine.